# How to use DTW/fastdtw to transform input time series

Tags: python, time-series, dtw

I want to transform two time series of unequal length to equal lengths so that they can be compared. I came across fastdtw. Does it only compute the distance and the path between the two arrays? Can we get two new vectors x ->x1 and y ->y1 such that x1 and y1 have equal length and can be compared?

```
from fastdtw import fastdtw
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

x = np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [10,5]])
y = np.array([[2,2], [3,3], [4,4]])

distance, path = fastdtw(x, y, dist=euclidean)
```

Tried fastdtw but did not get the expected result